# Variables defined in <?php to be included with form when submitted

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-validate, google-geocoding-api

I have a form that the user fills out the company information.  I then use jquery to validate the addresses and within the submitHandler I have the following script to get the long/lat of the validated address, but the long/lat is not being submitted with the form.  (I currently have the address for long/lat lookup hard coded in the link for testing purpose.)  Also note, you will need to provide your own API key for Google Maps API v3 which you can get [HERE.](https://code.google.com/apis/console)

NOTE: I am having difficulty with Stack Overflow's syntax highlighter so linking the code from PastBin.

[This is the script for the long/lat](http://pastebin.com/zKTiqhAW)

---

Because of limitation on number of links I could post, I will post links to the rest of my code *hopefully* after this post.

Comment: This is the full page scripts

[header.html (header for both pages)] <http://pastebin.com/Zxqh0sPj>

[NewCompany.php (This is the body of where the form is filled out)] <http://pastebin.com/uaAvsCfJ>

[footer.html (footer for both pages)] <http://pastebin.com/phyuB0Kc>

[NewCompanySubmit.php (This is the body of where the page would submit the data into the database)] <http://pastebin.com/ZDUT1Sq6>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two hidden inputs into the form for the lat and lng, then when the geocoding completes fill in the values of those inputs.

Comment: How would I fill in the hidden inputs from the geocoding script? (I had thought of using the hidden inputs, but did not know how to set them from that point)

Comment: Maybe im misunderstanding your question.  When the submit button is pressed you use jquery(ajax) to get the latlng before submitting the form?

Comment: Yes, I have the jquery first validate that the address is correct, then within the submit handler (as that is where the validator execute the scripts if all rules are valid)  I did it that way because I wanted to get the long/lat of a validated address.

Comment: so when you get the lat lng put it in the hidden inputs

Comment: How? by doing <input type="hidden" name="Lng" id="Lng"> and then when I set the value do $Lng = Lng ?

Comment: Thank you for your help @Galen I am changing my script a bit as I found a way of getting a map of the address with just the address, and that I dont need to get the coordinates for the Google Maps API like I had originally planned, so I am no longer need the Google Geocode API